# JTable won't display Unicode correctly when the application is executed from the command line or a jar file. It works fine in eclipse, though

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, command-line, jtable

I'm writing an application that reads a text file containing a list of vocabulary words in both English and Chinese.  These are then displayed in a JTable.  When I run or debug the app in Eclipse, everything displays fine.  I can see and read the characters and the English.  However, when I execute the app from the command line or from an executable jar, it's all wrong.  The characters show up as either squares or as gibberish.

I also have a text box that when I type Chinese into it, it displays correctly.

My first thought was that it was a font problem.  I was using a font installed on my system.  Since I can't guarantee that the person using this app will have that font, I moved it to a resource folder and load the font from a file.  The font appears as though it's been loaded so I'm convinced it's not a font issue.

I found another question that suggested using -Dfile.encoding=utf-8.  I've tried this and it did not work.

Would the brilliant folks at Stack Overflow have any advice on how to make this work?

Comment: Can you show us the code that reads the file's content? Especially how you open the `Reader`

Comment: I figured it out. You're absolutely right that it was a problem with the reader. I was opening it like: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));` and trusting Java to figure out the encoding of the file by itself. Stupid, foolish me. I've since changed the code to: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), "UTF8"));` and now it displays everything correctly.

Comment: I do still find it odd that it works from Eclipse but not from the command line.  It makes me wonder if somehow Eclipse changes the default character encoding for InputStreams.  I'm writing this on a non-chinese version of Windows.  I'm curious to see if I declared a reader like I was before, would it work on a Chinese Windows system due to a different default character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm writing this on a non-chinese version of Windows.

Well then you won't ever be able to get a Java program to produce Chinese command-line output.

Java, like almost all languages, uses the C standard library which has byte-based IO. The Windows command prompt interprets byte-based IO using the locale-specific default code page. That's never a UTF, so Unicode characters outside of the current locale's default code page just won't work.

(In theory you should be able to get it to work by changing your console fonts and using `chcp 65001` (UTF-8) together with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but in practice it doesn't work reliably due to bugs in the C runtime. Unicode on the command prompt is a long-standing sore point.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not outputting to the command line.  The problem was that it wasn't displaying in a JTable correctly when I run the program from the command line.  That is, when I would do something like `java com.randomwandering.vocabularyquizmaker.VocabularyQuizMaker` all the Chinese in the JTable would be garbled.  I have since discovered that I needed to specify the encoding for the input reader instead of trusting it to figure out the file was UTF-8.  Thank you very much, though.  I appreciate your answer.